# Path to application with spaces in package.json script

Tags: node.js, package.json

I am having problems with strings and spaces. when creating an alias for running a command in package.json (it fails becase cuts the command at the first space).

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "react-native-debugger:osx": "/Applications/React Native Debugger.app/Contents/MacOS/React Native Debugger"
    ...
  }
}
```

I require this, to be able to automate starting the environment to develop react native apps, and escaping using `\` does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont know if there is a better solution because the solution but the solution for me was to set the strings with spaces in single quotes (`'`)

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "react-native-debugger:osx": "/Applications/'React Native Debugger.app'/Contents/MacOS/'React Native Debugger'"
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: But this is linux only

Answer (score 4):

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": ".\\\"node modules\"\\.bin\\\"some folder\"\\protractor conf.js"
  },
```

use back slash and double quotes for windows.